# Sort random array in ascending order without arrays.sort

Tags: java

I am trying to sort an array of random numbers without using the arrays.sort. I have the code, but it doesn't work. not sure where is the error. Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Sort
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many numbers do you want? ");
        int howMany = in.nextInt();
        int [] myArray =  getRandomArray(howMany);

    }

    /* public static int bsearch(int[] arr, int key)
    {

    }*/

    public static int[] getRandomArray(int howMany) {
        int[] returnMe = new int[howMany]; // Assume size >= 0
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany ; i++) 
        returnMe[i] = rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + 1;
        //System.out.print(returnMe[i] + " ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= (howMany - 1); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < howMany - i -1; j++) 
            {
                int tmp = 0;
                if (returnMe[j] > returnMe[j+1])
                {
                    tmp = returnMe[j];
                    returnMe[j] = returnMe[j + 1];
                    returnMe[j + 1] = tmp; 
                }   
            }  
        }
        for ( int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
            System.out.println(returnMe[i] + " "); 
        return returnMe;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Does not work" means what, exactly?  Does not compile?  Compiles, but does not run?  Compiles and runs be emits an error (which?) or other incorrect output?

Comment: It compiles, run and gives output, but not in an ascending order(just random order) @JohnBollinger

Comment: You do realize, do you not, that you need to do more than name your class "Sort" to get it to perform actual sorting?  Because I don't see anything whatever in it that would do any sorting.

Comment: @DiabolicWords I am using BlueJ and it is not sorting it in ascending order.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have the coding in the getRandomArray method, it is the bubble sort method. You say , that it is wrong?

Comment: I say that a method named `getRandomArray()` is a darned poor place to put sorting code (or printing code).

Comment: I also say that actually testing your program shows that contrary to your assertion, it *does* sort the numbers into ascending order, excepting that the last may not be in its correct position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
        for (int j = 0; j < howMany - i -1; j++)
```

should be

```
        for (int j = 0; j <= howMany - i -1; j++)
```

or alternatively, remove the "-1" and keep "<". Otherwise, you will ignore the last number in the array. Everything else looks fine to me.

Comment: Happy to help :). Also, you could consider renaming the method to something like createRandomSortedArray, since createRandomArray implies its a yet-to-be sorted array. However, thats just to make the code easier to read&understand for others (which can actually be quite important if you don't just code for yourself).